# how to map multiple url for one servlet

Tags: java, struts, web.xml, struts-config

i am mapping two url with one servlet in my struts web application, the part of code in web.xml is bellow.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>3</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>detail</param-name>
      <param-value>3</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.mobile</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

the problem is whenever i am submitting any form, it is adding .mobile in url.for ex suppose the form is:

```
<html:form action="login.do">   
 <html:text property="name" />
 <html:submit >go</html:submit>                     
</html:form>
```

it is sending request to:

http:myIp:8080/ProjectName/login.mobile

My question is why it is adding .mobile instead of .do??is their any way to resolve it???

thanks.

Comment: Seriously? You'd better chech your jsp file.

Comment: no <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>action</servlet-name> <url-pattern>.do</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> is not there.In place of .do,*.do is there.

Comment: thats right. You must check your HTML then

Comment: when i am changing servlet mapping to <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> ,same jsps are working fine.

Comment: good! post the same as answer.

Comment: I think the container overwriting the **url pattern**. If you swipe ***.do** and ***.mobi** I guess you will get **login.do**. Better define another servlet **mobiAction**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe removing the extension (.do/.mobile) will help using

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/>
```